# Add form ID to JQuery form function

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, email

Im in need to create to separate e-mail forms based on AJAX and JQuery. 
I need one form to be Standart and other VIP, when getting email from website - i need to indicate from which form customer has send inquiry.
I have sample form for Standard, and need to create VIP form. Imagine it is needed to create forms ID and insert it to JQuery. 
Please help
Here is sample form code:

```
<form id="vip" class="pop_form" action="mail-vip.php">
    <h4>ОPlease leave your contacs, we will come back soon!</h4>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telephone" required />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
    <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Callback time" />
    <div align="center"><button  type="submit">Send</button></div>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $("form").serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.fancybox.close();
            }, 1000);
        });
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$recepient = "email;
$sitename = "Website";

$name = trim($_GET["name"]);
$phone = trim($_GET["phone"]);
$email = trim($_GET["email"]);
$email = trim($_GET["time"]);

$pagetitle = "New inquiry for \"$sitename\"";
$message = "Имя: $name \nTelephone: $phone \nE-mail: $email \nTime: $time";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
?>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various way you can do that.

One of the way could be (minimal change to your code)

Add an `hidden` field in your form which will be automatically sent to your `php` and extract it to see it's `type`.

e.g.   `<input type="hidden" name="type" value="vip">`

So it should look like,

```
<form id="vip" class="pop_form" action="mail-vip.php">
    <h4>ОPlease leave your contacs, we will come back soon!</h4>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Telephone" required />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
    <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Callback time" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="vip">
    <div align="center"><button  type="submit">Send</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: @MaksimMaksimenko  glad to help. Please can you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

form id is vip i think you need write $("#vip").submit
In the other word,the button where the type "submit " will also submit your form data ,so you don't need write the Ajax
query